# How to use ion-loading events "ionLoadingWillPresent"?

Tags: angular, ionic4

there. I want to know how to use Events "ionLoadingWillPresent" in Ionic V4 of ion-loading.

I know the IonLoading is a Interface, here's source code:

```
interface IonLoading extends JSXBase.HTMLAttributes<HTMLIonLoadingElement> {
//...
   'onIonLoadingWillPresent'?: (event: CustomEvent<void>) => void;
//...
}
```

Which is an interface.

Here's my code:

```
  constructor(
    public loadingController: LoadingController,
    public ionLoading: HTMLIonLoadingElement
  ) {}

  async triggerLoading() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: '',
      duration: 2000,
      backdropDismiss: false,
      showBackdrop: false,
      spinner: 'dots',
      translucent: false,
    });
    // Here is my try, I use getTop methods to get the Ion-Loading Elements.
    this.ionLoading = await this.loadingController.getTop();

    this.ionLoading.onIonLoadingWillPresent = ()=> {
      console.log('hello')
    };
    // events
    await loading.present();
    await loading.onDidDismiss();
    console.log('loading is didmissed!');
  }
```

--
Updated:

```
    this.loadingController.getTop().then(res => {
      res.addEventListener('ionLoadingWillPresent', (event: any) => {
        // no console from this code
        console.log(event);
      });
    });
```

--

But, petty, there's no property `onIonLoadingWillPresent` on ionLoading, how to use this event?

Such events like:

`ionLoadingDidDismiss`, `ionLoadingDidPresent`, `ionLoadingWillDismiss`, `ionLoadingWillPresent`.

On page: [ion-loading Api](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/loading)

I want to know how to use these events.Thanks a lot.

P.S: Not the methods `onDidDismiss`, `onWillDismiss` which the `ion-loading-controller` component already have.

Comment: Anyone can help? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can subscribe to the event like this:

```
this.ionLoading.addEventListener('ionLoadingWillPresent', (event: any) => {
});
```

If that doesn't fix it then I'm not sure if the way you get the ionLoading reference is right but I'll need to find a code snippet for that.

Comment: Cannot import IonLoading from '@ionic/angular', so cannot addEventListener like this. I use `getTop` methods from `IonLoadingController` can get the Elements of IonLoading, but CANNOT add EventListener in Promise or Element of it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is stuck on this trying to get willPresent for toast() to show, it's been refactored to handle its own events rather than the loading events as of v4, see https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast

`this.$ionic.toastController
                .create({blah}).then((t) => {
                    t.addEventListener("ionToastDidPresent", () => { on present })
}`

Comment: Thx, I will close the question.